# Sitecore 6.6 InvalidOperationException: 'Remember Me' checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

**Sitecore 6.6** login fails, irrespective of whether I check or un-check "Remember Me"

Though error details show the method, I cannot debug that as it is part of Sitecore DLL.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

'Remember Me' checkbox.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Remember Me' checkbox.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: 'Remember Me' checkbox.]
   Sitecore.sitecore.login.LoginPage.Login_LoggedIn(Object sender, EventArgs e) +984
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +289
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +93
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +84
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

Comment: Are you sure it's part of the original Sitecore dll? Namespace `Sitecore.sitecore.login` with Sitecore uppercase first and then Sitecore lowercase looks kind of suspicious... Is this a clean Sitecore instance? Did it work in the past and stopped working after you've done something?

Comment: can you try to delete your cookies and try again to login.

Comment: Have you modified the Login Page?

Comment: This is a existing old sitecore app. I wasn't part of its initial configuration, so I am not aware if this was modified. first of all I don't see a Login page or its code behind file for domain.com/sitecore/login

Comment: For the code behind, it is found in the Sitecore.Client.dll

Comment: @HishaamNamooya am I supposed to decompile it?

Comment: @HaBo, please see my answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact that the Remember Me checkbox ID is missing. Please see the decompiled code from the Sitecore.Client.dll below

```
  CheckBox checkBox = this.Login.FindControl("Remember") as CheckBox;
  Assert.IsNotNull((object) checkBox, "'Remember Me' checkbox.");
```

This is where it is crashing. In order to fix this, go to the login page, found in the following path: **Website\sitecore\login**. Open the **default.aspx** with a text editor and see if the remember checkbox ID is **Remember**

Comment: Yes it is. 
   <asp:CheckBox Style="margin-left: -4px" ID="Remember" runat="server" />

Comment: Can you decomplile the Sitecore.Client.dll and see in the namesapce Sitecore.sitecore.login if the code is as above?

Comment: Yes it is matching

Comment: Have you check the sitecore.client.dll from the Bin folder?